# ERROR in Angular2PiwikModule is not an NgModule

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, matomo, piwiktracker

While I' compile the code first time or try to build project using ng build --prod command it shows error.

I'v installed `"angular2piwik": "^0.1.7-beta"` and I'm using following versions:

```
"@angular/compiler": "2.4.9", 
"@angular/cli": "1.2.6", 
"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.9"
```

```
//app.module.ts file
import { Angular2PiwikModule } from "angular2piwik/dist";


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    Angular2PiwikModule
})
```

I expect to run project without any error, but actual it shows ERROR in Angular2PiwikModule is not an NgModule
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzJEj.png)

Comment: Have you tried to remove node_modules folder and execute "npm i" again?

Comment: yes..I tried this also.

Comment: @AshwiniDemouser check on this link its working without any error https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjtg7t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek but sample project is in angular 7, my project is already developed in angular 2, then what will be right configuration for that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to import `Angular2PiwikModule` like is in the official [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2piwik):

`import { Angular2PiwikModule } from 'angular2piwik';`

Answer (score 0):

Please update your `node_modules/angular2piwik/dist/index.d.ts` to

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

export * from './piwik-functions';
export * from './angular-piwik-components';

@NgModule({})
export class Angular2PiwikModule {}
```